# how can you record your screen in a gif?

Tags: macos, gif

[image]

This is the example i am talking about, how can you do this?

Comment: Try this open source GifCapture, which is written in Swift https://github.com/onmyway133/GifCapture

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46036/is-there-a-mac-screen-capture-tool-that-will-export-to-animated-gif/404520#404520

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I usually, on Mac, do this task with https://www.cockos.com/licecap/ (source: https://github.com/justinfrankel/licecap). It also runs on Windows.

> LICEcap can capture an area of your desktop and save it directly to .GIF (for viewing in web browsers, etc).

GUI is simple but effective, and it's really easy to select just the area you want to capture.

**Demo**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Comment for people with Big Sur, LICEcap doesn't work on it.

Comment: As a past LICEcap enthusiast I found Kap to be delightful: https://github.com/wulkano/Kap. `brew install --cask kap`

Comment: FWIW LICEcap v1.31 for macOS supports Big Sur and M1

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, LICEcap is fantastic!

Comment: LICEcap works on Mac M1, Ventura 13.4.

Comment: Doesn't work on Sonoma 14.

Comment: Now it works on the latest MacOS 14 on my M1 MBP.

Answer (score 66):

It depends on your platform, and there are a bunch of ways to do it.

On Mac OSX, there is a built-in QuickTime screen recorder.

1. Launch QuickTime Player
2. File menu -> New Screen Recording
3. Use the tool of your choice (such as ffmpeg) to convert the recording to a gif.

Here's an example of how to convert a recording .mov file to a gif:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -s 600x400 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -f gif - | gifsicle --optimize=3 --delay=3 > out.gif
```

See this link for more info and step by step: https://gist.github.com/dergachev/4627207

If you're on other platforms, or prefer to use a specific tool other than the built-in QuickTime, here are a few to consider:

- [Grabilla](http://grabilla.com/) Firefox Add-On
- [Animated GIF Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/animated-gif-capture/aecmckhhfknljgicfkpbinfkpnijehcm?hl=en) Chrome extension
- [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) for Windows and OSX

Comment: and you can turn it into a lightweight gif?

Comment: I hit this exact same thing. I ended up using Automator (macOS) + ffmpeg so anytime I save a movie to a specific folder, it automatically gets turned into a gif. I wrote it up here: https://www.ehfeng.com/gif-screen-recordings-on-macos/